# How to iterate thru a QList and group values together?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Currently I can enter values into the QList and show all values ,but would like to group same worker types together.
For Example all hourly workers together ,all salary workers together and same with commission workers.

Current iterator code:

```
EmployeeList::iterator i;
  for (i = EmpList.begin(); i != EmpList.end(); ++i)
  {

          cout << "Employee ID: " << (*i)->getID() << endl;
          cout << "Name: " << (*i)->getName() << endl;
          cout << "Type: " << (*i)->getPayment()->getType() << endl;
          cout << "Amount: " << (*i)->getPayment()->pay()<< endl;

  }
```

This displays as such:
[image: Example]

Comment: I have a little trouble understanding what you mean by "Would like to group same values together as type". Maybe you can add the expected/wanted output to your question as well?

Comment: Type of worker (Salary,Commision or Hourly) which you get thru the use of (*i)->getPayment()->getType() as there is only 3 types of of workers. Would like to group all Hourly workers together same with Commission and Salary.

Comment: Sounds like you want to sort with a custom comparator...

Comment: @JesperJuhl How do you go about this ? I am new to QT and need to group type's together but everything else in my program works already.

Comment: A simpler approach (but potentially less efficient), if you don't have too many different types of workers, might be simply iterating over the list once for every worker type...

Comment: Something along the lines of `std::sort(EmpList.begin(), EmpList.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.getPayment()->getType() < rhs.getPayment()->getType(); });` (or use `std::stable_sort` if you need to preserve existing order of identical elements) - nothing Qt specific about it.

Comment: @Aconcagua I have tried doing this, with specific if type == "Salary" {do this}

Comment: @KazyKamakaze Hopefully, type is a `std::string` - if it is of type `char (const)*`, you need to compare with `strcmp`!

Comment: @JesperJuhl it provides an error when I do something like that." error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter"

Comment: @Aconcagua It's type of QString.

Comment: You need to be building as c++14 or c++17 or change `auto` to the explicit list element type.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze Strings come with the risk of typos, and comparison is case sensitive ("salary" != "Salary"). I'd rather define my own enum for, possibly together with an `operator<<` overload that prints the strings to the stream...

Comment: @JesperJuhl What do I need to put in lhs and rhs as they will be unused parameters?

Comment: They are *not* unused. Read the lambda body. Their types need to be the type of the elements in the list you are sorting (but if you can build as C++14/17 then `auto` is the easy way out - I assumed C++17 availability since you didn't specify a specific version).

Comment: @Aconcagua The type's are hard coded in and can only choose 1,2 or 3 so no typo's otherwise it won't compile correctly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'll install newer compiler and retry.

Comment: Or maybe just turn on C++14 support for your existing compiler (for example, for gcc, add `-std=c++14`).

Comment: @KazyKamakaze Probably you have a C++14 compliant compiler already. Try to add `CONFIG += c++14` into your `*.pro` file, if you use qt build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to C++14 or C++17 then this:

```
std::sort(EmpList.begin(), EmpList.end(),
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs->getPayment()->getType() < rhs->getPayment()->getType();
     });
```

Should do what you need.

If you are using C++11 then:

```
std::sort(EmpList.begin(), EmpList.end(),
    [](const WhateverTypeIsInEmployeeList& lhs, const WhateverTypeIsInEmployeeList& rhs) {
        return lhs->getPayment()->getType() < rhs->getPayment()->getType();
     });
```

Should do the job.

For C++98/03 you will need to write a function/class to use in place of the lambda.

(Btw; I'm assuming that the type returned by `getPayment()->getType()` has a `operator<` that satisfies the strict weak ordering requirement needed for `std::sort` to work)

Comment: Isn't it suppose to lhs->getPayment()->getType() rather than lhs.getPayment()->getType() , since it's a list of Pointers to objects?

Comment: Just gimme a sec, once I added Config += c++17 compiler freaked out.

Comment: @Kazy Kamakaze Maybe you should tell us (in the question) what compiler/compiler version you are using (and on what platform/OS). The build system you are using would also be useful info.

Comment: Got it to work, Thank you! You were correct about the compiler issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze - Happy to help. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

this is unrelated and the question has already been solved but you dont need to dereference the pointer the arrow operator does it for you

```
//dont do this v
(*i)->getName();
//you can just do this
i->getName();
```

its not required but the way you do it looks ugly. if you really wanted to be super "proper" you could

```
(*i).getName();
```

but anyways stick w/ the arrow operator

Comment: Of course `(*p)->` and `p->` are not equivalent - lots of code would break if it suddenly were so. Here `p` is an **iterator** in a container of **pointers**, so indeed it has to be dereferenced twice.